# Identify user via external identification service (SSO) for client server app

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, single-sign-on, client-server

## Start point

I have a Flutter **mobile application** which exchanges data with its **own server** using REST API. Currently all endpoints are public, so no authentication is implemented.

*Note: The server is currently implemented in [Conduit](https://pub.dev/packages/conduit), but any other alternatives are welcome.*

## Requirement

I need to introduce authentication function in the mobile application. E.g. let the user to identify himself with his Google/Facebook/other social account.

## Assumption / Challenge

There are a lot of implementations, that allow user to login in the mobile app itself using 3rd party services.

But it is not clear how integrate the server to this process. Theoretically the server should verify the user using his ID and some token by the identification service.

I would rather use any available library, than implement it my myself to reduce possible errors on implementation.

## Exchange between client, server and identification service

I see the following sequence:

1. Client sends a login request to the identification service
2. Identification service returns identification result, e.g. an identification token
3. Client sends the identification token to the server
4. Server sends the identification token to the identification service to verify the user
5. Identification server sends back verification result
6. Server returns confirmation to the client
7. Client starts normal data exchange

Run snippet to display sequence diagram:

```js
mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<pre class="mermaid">
sequenceDiagram
    Client->>ID service: Login
    ID service->>Client: ID token
    Client->>Server: Login
    Server->>ID service: Verify
    ID service->>Server: Verification result
    Server->>Server: Check/Register
    Server->>Client: Server token
    Client->Server: Data exchange
</pre>
```

## Questions

1. Is there any library or service, that implement user identification for both client (mobile app) and server?
2. Is the exchange sequence above in general correct? What can be modified there?
3. Is there any best practices how to implement such identification mechanism?

Any further advice is welcome.

Comment: Would this help: https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2

Comment: @RichardHeap using OAuth protocol is a good idea to secure private endpoints. The suggested library is low-level enough and implies that the developer implements the most part of the logic. Conduit itself contains a simple implementation of OAuth here https://docs.theconduit.dev/tut/oauth2/ as well as the sibling project https://pub.dev/packages/angel3_auth_oauth2.